# British Columbia - Pros and Cons of Joint Tenancy/Bare Trust of Private Property

Tags: canada, property, british-columbia

What are the pros and, especially, cons of becoming a joint tenant and bare trustee of a private property in British Columbia? I keep finding articles on the pros, but not too much on the cons.